# Asterisk AGI: How to get or set the value of a global variable?

Tags: php, asterisk, telephony, agi

I'm using Asterisk 1.8 with PHP for AGI scripting.

EDIT:

I'm struggling with setting and obtaining the values of global variables from within an AGI PHP script. I can set channel variables but not global variables. Using PHPAGI lib.

Tried:

```
Set({$varname}={$value},g)
Set({$varname}=\"{$value}\",g)
Set(GLOBAL({$varname})={$value})
```

That does not seem to work at all, when getting the value from within the dial plan, it is empty.

Does anyone have a working example of setting and getting global variables in an AGI script?

Comment: I have no experience with Asterisk but with php you can access global variables from [`$GLOBALS`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Comment: No, I'm talking about an Asterisk dial plan global variable, which can be set via an external program or script using the Asterisk Gateway Interface (AGI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround to make it work.

First, the global variable must not be declared in the dial plan under the [globals] section. And, it seems you cannot set a global variable from within an AGI script. However, you can set a channel variable (local to the current channel). So to set a global variable from an AGI script, you first set the value to a channel variable and when you return from the script into the dial plan, you retrieve the value of the channel variable and assign it to a global variable. Basically, it seems you can only assign global variables from within the dial plan, not from within an AGI script.

sample code:

```
//in dial plan

exten => _XXXX,n,AGI(myagiscript.php)
exten => _XXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(someGlobalVariable)=${myLocalVar})


// in myagiscript.php

$agi->set_variable("myLocalVar", "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk [wiki info about AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI) says different things about global variables:
*...
Global variables are not passed to the AGI script in this manner. You must get them using the "get variable" AGI command...*

and in other part: *...GET VARIABLE: Does not work with global variables. Does not work with some variables that are generated by modules....*

For setting global value you can execute:

```
EXEC SetGlobalVar <var_name>=<value>
```

For getting I thing that `get_variable` should work but there was bug in Asterisk: https://issues.asterisk.org/view.php?id=7609

This bug was in Asterisk 1.2.20, what version of Asterisk do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8. Unfortunately, SetGlobalVar() is not there anymore in that version.

Comment: I'm using 16.9.0 and getting [globals] variables is not working.