# Can I hide the clients number from users when using asterisk?

Tags: php, numbers, asterisk, crm

I have an asterisk system which I use to make outgoing calls. I've been trying to hide the number from users so that they click to call but without knowing the number they are calling. I have tried to base64 encode the number, but I don't know where to decode it in asterisk for the call to go through. Anyone has this problem?

Comment: If those users run Chrome browser, there is an extension that can do this called Tel Linker by KOTRS You could set the Link Text Format option to display (xxx) xxx-xxxx while the click still pass the number to tel: or sip: protocol handlers.. eg. softphones

Comment: U dint get me,when a user click the number the softphone eybeam launches and calls the number ,i want to send eybeam an 64 bit encoded version of the number and i dont know where to decode this in the asterisk server for the call to come through

Comment: Actually I did get you. What I proposed was hiding the number on the webpage but still making it clickable and dialable by your softphones. It makes no sense to display the number to users (which I assume are humans) but encrypt the number that your software uses, which frankly could care less what the number is as long as it's valid. Either way, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just write custom AGI script which will decode a number from base64. And make sure that calls are hitting that script.

Below you can find example dialplan:

```
exten => _.,1,AGI(myscript.php)
exten => _.,n,Dial(SIP/yoursipprovider/${number})
exten => _.,n,Hangup()
```

Make sure that you are using `_.` extension, because `X` only match a digit, but `_.` pattern will match everything.

Your script `myscript.php` should take value from ${EXTEN} base64 decode it and set result to variable ${number}.

Comment: you can also use dial function in AGI script

Comment: but how can the script get the value from the exten this is what im struggling with

Comment: please check link below, same logic only use get_variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604257/asterisk-agi-how-to-get-or-set-the-value-of-a-global-variable

Answer (score 0):

Realy hide number is: use in page number's id in database, use in click2call script func_odbc or other mysql lookup for number based on that id.

Base64 decoding may help only if all your users have low IT skills.